# Rails testing JavaScript with Capybara

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I am new to TDD. I run Capybara `integration` tests to test `javascript`

```
test "should validate project", :js => true do
  visit root_path
  click_link "myId"
end
```

but I keep on getting this error message

```
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb:25:in `test': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from test/integration/projects_test.rb:7:in `<class:ProjectsTest>'
    from test/integration/projects_test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you share your spec/spec_helper.rb file? or your Gemfile?